# How to get bold "Table No." with a period after the number instead of a colon?

Tags: tables, tabularx

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{Results}
    \begin{tabularx}{14.36cm}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        Column  & c1 & c2 & c3 & c4 & c5 \\ 
        \hline
        r1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
        r2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The output gives the table heading as "Table 1: Results"

Instead, I want "**Table 1.** Results"

Comment: Off-topic but why do you use `tabularx` if you don't have any `X` column?

Comment: @CarLaTeX I think it's for the `width` parameter that it's required. Here is set to `14.36cm`

Comment: @Moriambar Yes, but I don't still understand the reason of such a table...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use the `caption` package, as in:

`\usepackage[labelfont=bf,labelsep=period]{caption}`

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,labelsep=period]{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \footnotesize
    \centering
    \caption{Results}
    \begin{tabularx}{14.36cm}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        Column  & c1 & c2 & c3 & c4 & c5 \\ 
        \hline
        r1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
        r2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Yielding:

[image]

---

Anyway as @CarLaTeX pointed out, the result is ugly, not because of the use of `tabularx`, but mainly because the table was typeset with a fixed length which produced an ugly column on the right, to fit the whole screen

I took the liberty of changing a bit of what the OP posted, to typeset a better-looking table in my opinion. Being that the matter is solved, I leave it here as an alternative solution.

I basically lose the `tabularx` package (not needed) and included `booktabs` (for the different rules). I also losed the vertical separators (typographically ugly) and rationalized the horizontal ones.

Also I included extra data. I think that, to typeset the table any better one has to know much more of what is to be typeset in those column and that is not something that can be discussed in this answer (at least: it can but it is offtopic).

I suggest OP to try the code (if he wants to) and ask another question whenever he feels the need for it.

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article} 
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
    \caption{Results}
    \begin{tabular}{cccccc}
        \toprule
        Column  & c1 & c2 & c3 & c4 & c5 \\ 
        \midrule
        r1 & 0 & 100 & 50 & text & 0 \\ 
        r2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
        \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]